# Search and replace string

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

Need command help to replace the text in string from start and just before the first number. I have a data frame with all these place name and address in single field but only need address extracted from string.

using this `gsub` command to replace the string,

```
gsub("^.*?\\d","","Gilroy Plant Place 777 Morello Ave")

[1] "77 Morello Ave"
```

required output:

```
777 Morello Ave
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `\D` and this thing matches any character but not of a digit. `^\D*` means from the start `^` match zero or more `*` non digit characters `\D`.

```
sub("^\\D*","","Gilroy Plant Place 777 Morello Ave")
# [1] "777 Morello Ave"
```

Comment: Short and killer exp!

Comment: @Avinash Raj, thanks for your reply. One additional question if you can help. Using this Sub command on data frame column. Is there a way to flag changes made by sub command:                                                                      datafile2$HOME_STREETLINE_2 <- sub("^\\D*","",datafile2$HOME_STREETLINE_1)

Comment: @scorpionz I think you meant `datafile2[datafile2 $HOME_STREETLINE_2=='',]`. right?

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub(".*?(\\d.*)","\\1","Gilroy Plant Place 777 Morello Ave")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
^.*?(?=\d)
```

What a positive lookahead does is that it looks ahead of the string and see if a sub pattern matches. If it does, match the stuff before the sub pattern. In the above regex, `^.*?` will only be matches if the string after it matches `\d`, but the `\d` part won't be in the match.